# Not worked true tooltip box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Don't know why the tooltip box(class `.show_tooltip`) shows up on the left when mouse enters on `li a`. I want to display each tooltip box on top of the same link that mouse is, i.e. just above/left of the link. Links have to be on the right just as they are now, so please do not change my html code) **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AQh6y/3/)**

Example : Mouseover on "how": What can I do to get it like this?

[image]

These codes are a small specimen part from my original code, which is quite long.

**CSS:**

```
.show_tooltip{
    background-color: #E5F4FE;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: #5A5959 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    color: #0C0C0C;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;*/
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>    
    <div class="show_tooltip">
        put returns between paragraphs
    </div>
        <a href="#">about</a>
    </li>

    <li>    
    <div class="show_tooltip">
        for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
    </div>
        <a href="#">how</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("li a").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).prev().fadeIn();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
            $('.tooltip').css('bottom', e.pageY - 10);
            $('.tooltip').css('right', e.pageX + 10);
        }).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).prev().fadeOut();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are making the markup complicated that way, but since you told not to modify the HTML, here's what you can do to place the tooltip just next to the link.

Working Demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/bikerabhinav/AQh6y/8/

Explanation:
Get the width of parent container (to act as the axis/base)

```
    var t = $('ul').outerWidth();
```

Get the left-offset of link :

```
var l = $(this).offset();
```

Apply these to the CSS of tooltip. Position it absolutely:

```
$("li a").mouseenter(function(){
    var l = $(this).offset();
    var t = $('ul').outerWidth();
$(this).prev().css({right:t+20-l.left,top:l.top}).fadeIn();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('.tooltip').css('bottom', e.pageY - 10);
        $('.tooltip').css('right', e.pageX + 10);
     }).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).prev().fadeOut();
});
```

PS: this is more of a hack basically, but I hope you get what I'm trying to do here. A much better way would be if you clean up the HTML

Comment: it not work true in my projct, see you: [link](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/order_foreign_tour_insert)

Comment: It is because your HTML markup is incorrect. Works fine in Chrome/FF (WHY are you continuously modifying the link you gave? how are we supposed to see what's wrong?)
Anyways, correct the HTML + CSS first

Comment: Ok, i put HTML original in [link](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/order_foreign_tour_insert), Please see you and tell me, what is problem? {i changed link because i use of codeigniter, i think that maybe problem is from it and can not put it in jsfiddel. Please you see this [LINK](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/order_foreign_tour_insert) and tell me what's wrong and what should change in HTML and CSS?}

Answer (score 0):

is that you want -->  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AQh6y/4/)**

change `position: fixed;` in `.show_tooltip{}`

Comment: what u want, i din't get u?? do u want that tootip shoud comes just above the link hoverd??